# How to find jar for com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo?

Tags: java, jar

Looking for the `jar` file for `com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo`, how can I find it?

I tried

http://www.findjar.com/index.x

but came up empty.  Would anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!  It is located here:

http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html

You can download the jar from here